# PhoneGap Web View for IOS 6 is Open with Built in Browser

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cordova

My Company Required from me to develop Hybrid Mobile app using `PhoneGap` I Built a release for android platform and it worked very will, but i face difficulties in iPhone..

I used 
- `mac iOSx 10.7` , `xcode 4.6`, `cordova 3.3`, `iphone ios6` simulater.

Scenarios i did :

1. I added the plugins (camera, geolocation, barcode,…etc) to my app.
2. I copied www folder and i paste it in my web Application on the server side "for ex. webContent).
3. To make a web view for my iPhone app if followed the tutorial in the link http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/uiwebview-tutorial/239/
4. The Final result : there is pop up message "alert" message appears in my web App, it seems that the url is run on web browser so this message will appears

   gap:`["PluginManager","startup","PluginManager187531576"]`

   How Shall I fix it ???
   and in android there is apk files what are the equvilent in iPhone and how to deploy it ?

Comment: First of all, you don't have to use a UIWebView, follow the iOS getting started guide. Second, you have to use the cordova.js for iOS, you are probably using the cordova.js for android

Comment: so .. for each platform has its own `cordova.js` file , isn't it ?

Comment: @jcesar you are right … `cordova.js` was for `android` , actually i created two folders one named `android` and `iOS` and each folder got his own `www` folder and calling 'cordova.js' in the head depending on device…and the alert box is vanished.